# How enable ctrl + v paste in redhat?

Tags: terminal

I've installed Red Hat 6.5 and see that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> does not work. It just prints <kbd>^V</kbd> in the console instead of pasting from the clipboard.

What can be wrong? How can I enable pasting using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>?

Comment: Nothing is "wrong": Ctrl-v for pasting is an OSX/Windows pattern, you are using Linux. Use Shift-Insert instead...

Comment: Are you using the text mode console or a terminal emulator in the GUI? If a terminal emulator, which one? What made you expect that Ctrl+V would paste from the clipboard?

Answer (score 2):

I think the option of enabling <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> varies from emulator to emulator, but there are easy ways around this most of the time:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> works as a paste in most terminal emulators I've used. Your mileage may vary, so you can check if your emulator has a similar keyboard shortcut (usually an afterthought in gray font after opening the menu "Edit > Paste") if that doesn't work off the bat.
- Highlighting text automatically "copies" it to a magic clipboard independent of your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{XCV}</kbd> buffer. Simply middle-click (press down your mouse wheel, or multiple-finger-tap on your laptop touchpad, depending on how you've enabled middle-click emulation on that) to paste text that is highlighted. (I have a bad habit of lazily highlighting random text as I read things on reddit, and that leaves me with occasional bizarre disjointed surprises when I middle-click into my terminal.)